# JHipster connect to H2 DB with external SQL editor

Tags: jhipster

I can connect to my H2 DB in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8081/h2-console/login.jsp?jsessionid=649273874cf6ca550067b7f4bc033497
```

With Dbvisualizer I can connect but my schema and tables are not there?

Connect string for browser:

```
jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/my;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

I have tried:

```
jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/my;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc:h2:file:<absolute path>/my;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/my;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/<absolute path>/my;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

What JDBC string should I use for an external tool?

Comment: The jdbc url you use is for embedded connection, you get one db per jvm. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes

Comment: OK, so how can I connect to my DB in my JVM from Dbvisualizer or other external tool? The DB file is on disk, so I don't understand why I can't connect with the string.

Comment: Probably using tcp like jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/myuser

Comment: Did not work...

Comment: Have you tried on port 9092? This is the default tcp port in h2 doc

Comment: Did not work. I have the http that work in my browser. I use default JHipster, does someone know the exact connect string for an external tool such as DbVisualizer or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You should use http:\localhost:h2-consol and connect to your database.

**Link to connect h2 DB JHipster:**

[image: link to connect h2 DB JHipster]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

Here is how to configure it in IntelliJ Idea.

[image: Here is how to configure in IntelliJ]

[image]